# Using the transitive verb "optimize"

Tags: verbs, transitivity

The verb *optimize* isn't intransitive therefore isn't ergative, so how could we use it like below? By the way, as far as I know using transitive verbs intransitively is not grammatical/possible.

*The **string** has to do more things. It is harder to optimize.*

I think it should at least be:
*The **string** has to do more things. It is harder to be optimized.*

What are your ideas, guys?

Comment: Context please and source of the sentences.

Comment: Btw, I do not know why you bold *the string*.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with your premise that "optimize" is a transitive verb, but I don't think objects should necessarily be overt; they can be covert as in your example

> The string has to do more things. It is harder to optimize <s>it</s>

We call this a *tough construction* *, in which the subject in the main clause is the implied object in the infinitival clause. This contruction is permitted by tough adjectives—e.g *easy, hard, difficult*.

The passive counterpart is not possible since it doesn't take an object.

---

*<sub>Biber et al in the Longman Student Grammar of Spoken and Written English analyze it as an object-to-subject raising; I don't like this term, however, because it can be confusing to learners. *Tough contruction* is a good term because it reminds you of the tough adjectives.</sub>

Comment: +1, Thank you for your answer. Do you mean **It is harder to be optimized** is incorrect? I didn't get your reason for that, rightly.

Comment: @Abbasi The tough adjective needs the subject in the main clause to be the object in the infinitival clause. So the passive construction, which doesn't take an object, is not correct. (Cf. **It's harder to be optimized it.*)

Comment: I don't agree with this part. :-) What is your source about the case please?

Comment: @Abbasi "[T]he subject of the sentence is identified with the unexpressed object of the infinitive clause, which must therefore have a transitive verb; hence the unacceptable *Bob is hard to arrive" (Quirk et al., 1985, p. 1229). A passivised verb is no longer transitive.